# How to deal with this in equality?

Tags: inequality

In an equation like this $|x + 3| = 2$, I know I can do something like $x + 3 = 2$ or $x + 3 = -2$ and solve for $x$ from there on. How do I solve it in this situation? $|x + 3| > 2$. Can I apply the same rule?

Comment: Same rule. $|x+3|>2$ would mean one of $(x+3)>2$ or $(x+3)<-2$.

Comment: Why is the sign changed for negative case?

Comment: Good question. Think about it again. $(-3) < (-2)$, but $|-3|=3 , |-2| = 2$  and $3>2$. Absolute value means that we do not care about sign, we care only about how large the number without the sign is. However, sign matters to the $>$ symbol, because even if $55555>1$, if you put a negative sign, $-55555<1$, the sign has changed, and the comparison has flipped. To preserve this, the second case above flips the comparison. I hope you see why, once again: We care only about the magnitude of the number, not it's sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule remains similar. $|x+3|>2$ can imply one of two things: $x+3>2$ or $x+3<-2$.

The reason why the sign flips in the second case above is because the absolute value function does not look at the sign of your number: To give an example, $-3 < -2$ but $3>2$, and the absolute function will give the result $|-3|=3>|-2|=2$. In the above, when we put a minus sign, the order of the comparison flips, while the absolute value does not correct that. Thus, it is up to us to correct it, and we do  it by flipping the sign of the second expression again : $x+3 < -2$ means that $x+3$ is smaller than $-2$ **considering sign**, but the numbers smaller than $-2$ go like $-3,-4,-5,...$ : their absolute value is increasing, although  the numbers themselves are decreasing. This justifies the flip of the sign.